# Extract object from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have this text as string in javascript:

```
'ConversationMessage.edit({"conversation_message_id":1901,"conversation_id":154,"resource_id":112,"message":"Great :)","sent_datetime":"2017-05-22T10:04:16.583Z","message_type":0,"display_name":"Hammad Rasheed","resource_image":"http://whuntulocal.s3.amazonaws.com/1492584389-Shot.png","messageattachment_id":null,"message_id":null,"directory_name":null,"filename":null})'
```

I want to extract the object from that. Meaning I want extract what was passed to `ConversationMessage.edit()` as parameter.

I have tried `JSON.parse()` but that is failing. 
I have tried to `str.split()` to split ")" and "(" character but that does not work either because the message property in the object can contain ")" string as well, as it is currently containing "Great :)".

Here is the source of HTML where this string gets extracted:

```
<span class="message-date text-navy"><i class="fa fa-pencil text-success cursor-pointer message-edit-pencil" onclick="ConversationMessage.edit({&quot;conversation_message_id&quot;:1901,&quot;conversation_id&quot;:154,&quot;resource_id&quot;:112,&quot;message&quot;:&quot;Great {{{{{{{&quot;,&quot;sent_datetime&quot;:&quot;2017-05-22T10:04:16.583Z&quot;,&quot;message_type&quot;:0,&quot;display_name&quot;:&quot;Hammad Rasheed&quot;,&quot;resource_image&quot;:&quot;http://whuntulocal.s3.amazonaws.com/1492584389-Shot.png&quot;,&quot;messageattachment_id&quot;:null,&quot;message_id&quot;:null,&quot;directory_name&quot;:null,&quot;filename&quot;:null})"></i> Monday, 22 May 2017, 15:04 </span>
```

Comment: Can you provide more examples of the string i.e do they all start with `'ConversationMessage.edit(`

Comment: don't you have access to edit method of conversationMessage

Comment: @Downvoters Reason for downvote?
I take take the onclick attribute of the element. That is in above form as shown. The data is variable in that but format will always be same

Comment: try to fix the source of your JSON object, using regex on the client side to clean your invalid JSON object is not a good logic

Comment: @MinaGabriel Perhaps this is a scrape from another site, and they don't have access to change it?

Comment: @Hammad this is even worse, your application will crash at any time if any changes made to this object, now you have to think about the endless number of validations to this object, Good Luck!

Comment: Not a scrape. I need to extract that from my html and want to read the current message content from onclick attribute. I added the HTML above.

Comment: Is that HTML generated by you? It would be better in many ways to either store the object in memory where you could pull it cleanly whenever needed, or at least store the object separately in a data-attribute so you don't need to parse it from the code.

Comment: @JJJ Yes that might be better way to go about it. I was thinking the same. To use data attributes rather than passing whole object as argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take the substring of the string starting from the first `{` character and ending at the `}` character plus one i.e

```js
var a = 'ConversationMessage.edit({"conversation_message_id":1901,"conversation_id":154,"resource_id":112,"message":"Great :)","sent_datetime":"2017-05-22T10:04:16.583Z","message_type":0,"display_name":"Hammad Rasheed","resource_image":"http://whuntulocal.s3.amazonaws.com/1492584389-Shot.png","messageattachment_id":null,"message_id":null,"directory_name":null,"filename":null})'
console.log(JSON.parse(a.substring(a.indexOf('{'), a.lastIndexOf('}') + 1)));
```

Comment: If the message contains `Great :}` instead of `Great :)`, this will fail.

Comment: I'm still a fan of my regex option, even though haters are going to hate on regex.

Comment: Thankyou @FrankerZ I have changed indexOf to last index that should help that issue :) I don't know any more test cases

Comment: That works good. But I am not sure if that will always work if the message contains multiple { or }. 
Will it?

Comment: Im not sure, if you provide some better example of input i may be able to make a more robust solution

Comment: Thanks. I tested that with multiple } and {

Comment: What if the string has more than one object, how can you extract the first one?

Answer (score 2):

Simple regex should work:

```js
var str = 'ConversationMessage.edit({"conversation_message_id":1901,"conversation_id":154,"resource_id":112,"message":"Great :)","sent_datetime":"2017-05-22T10:04:16.583Z","message_type":0,"display_name":"Hammad Rasheed","resource_image":"http://whuntulocal.s3.amazonaws.com/1492584389-Shot.png","messageattachment_id":null,"message_id":null,"directory_name":null,"filename":null})';

var objString = /^ConversationMessage\.edit\((.*)\)$/.exec(str);

var obj = JSON.parse(objString[1]);

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? You even mention the remote possibility of regex, and downvotes go flying. This is a perfectly legitimate place to use regex...and works if the object contains '{' or '}' within the object strings.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in javascript, someone might provide you better javascript solution but for your current string try below regex you will get the result in first group,

```
ConversationMessage\.edit\((\{.*\})\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZUIQO6/1)